# Why does GA4 load 3 times when creating the event table in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging, google-analytics-4

I want to know when the events table creation job is completed by using Cloud Logging.

```
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.projectId="PROJECT_ID"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId="DATASET_ID"

protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId="TABLE_ID"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.writeDisposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
```

but I've checked that GA4 loads 3 times when creating the event table at Cloud Logging.
[image]

And my question is that

1. why does GA4 load 3 times when creating the event table in Bigquery?
2. Which cloud logging query will tell me when the final event table is created?

Thanks in advance. and have a nice day everyone seeing this stupid question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [User-defined log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#user-metrics) and The [AuditData messages](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#auditdata_format) in BigQuery audit logs, you can create an Alert policy that lets you know when a BigQuery table is created.

> The audit log message system relies on structured logs, and the
> BigQuery service provides three distinct kinds of messages:
>
> - AuditData: The old version of logs, which reports API invocations.
> - BigQueryAuditMetadata: The new version of logs, which reports    resource interactions such as which tables were read from and written
>   to by a given query job and which tables expired due to having an
>   expiration time configured.
> - AuditLog: The logs that BigQuery Reservations and BigQuery    Connections use when reporting requests.

Using **BigQueryAuditMetadata**, specifically the **BigQueryAuditMetadata.TableCreation** event, you can create the filter for your alerting policy using the JSON format.

```
{
  "table": {
    object (BigQueryAuditMetadata.Table)
  },
  "reason": enum (BigQueryAuditMetadata.TableCreation.Reason),
  "jobName": string
}
```

> To create a distribution metric by using the Google Cloud CLI, specify
> the full metric configuration using the **--config-from-file** flag. The
> configuration format is JSON or YAML. For a full description of the
> LogMetric configuration, see [projects.metrics.](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.metrics)

For more detailed information about:

- Creating a [Distribution metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics#create-distribution), step 5 provides information
  about using logging query language.
- [BigQuery sample queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library-preview#bigquery-filters).
- [Logging Query Language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language).

Comment: As you said, BigQueryAuditMetadata is better than AuditData at catching duplicate logs. Thanks for your perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

### Logging query for new GA4 export tables created on BigQuery

This query will only match the initial table creation entries so you get one log event per day.

```
protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
protoPayload.metadata.tableCreation.reason="JOB"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission:"bigquery.tables.create"
NOT protoPayload.resourceName:"_intraday" -- ignore intraday table creation
```

### Multiple GA4 exports connected to a single BigQuery project

Isolate specific tables by replacing `DATASET_NAME` with the relevant id from your BigQuery dataset.

```
protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
protoPayload.metadata.tableCreation.reason="JOB"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission:"bigquery.tables.create"
NOT protoPayload.resourceName:"_intraday" -- ignore intraday table creation
protoPayload.resourceName:"DATASET_NAME/tables/events_" -- OPTIONAL for BigQuery projects connected to more than one GA4 export
```